# Is it safe to remove Firefox this way?

Tags: firefox

is it safe to remove Firefox like this:

```
sudo apt purge firefox             <<--- remove firefox and all the files it came with.
sudo apt autoremove --purge        <<--- remove orphans and their files...
sudo apt clean                     <<--- clean the cash
```

is it safe to run these commands  ? Will they mess something up ? last time i did this, some crucial packages were removed too...so can someone confirm ?

Comment: It is OK. The last one is unrelated.

Comment: This will remove whatever `-desktop` metapackage you're using is if it depends on Firefox for installation of software being shipped with your flavor.  But 'crucial packages' could mean anything so without more details of what you're seeing getting removed we can't really answer whether this is 'sane' or not

Comment: If you want to see what an apt command is going to do, you can run it in simulation mode. For example, `sudo apt purge -s firefox`.

Comment: it says it will remove firefox*